# Loading controller from partial

Tags: angularjs

I would to dynamically load controller in my partial file so my code is better organized.  Through my [research](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0), I found that if I want to load controller from partial using the script tag, I need to include JQuery.

However, these approach seem to only work if my controller is declared in the global scope, i.e.

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {}
```

If I switch to using module in my controller.js

```
angular.module ("myApp").controller ("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {});
```

this no longer work with the error message 
**"Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"**

Below is a plunker to demonstrate this.

http://plnkr.co/wNv3UD

How could I make this work?

**Note**
I did not include controller.js in index.html intentionally.  I want to load controller from the partial.html, since it would only be used there.

**Edit**
I was able to achieve what I wanted to to after reading this question: [AngularJS Dynamic loading a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674945/angularjs-dynamic-loading-a-controller)

This seem to be a straightforward approach to support lazy loading.  Hopefully the $controllerProvider.register method could be exposed through angular.module.controller in future versions to support lazy loading.

Comment: you forgot to include your `<script src="controller.js"></script>` in the `<head>` and since you declared `var app` to be your module use it `app.controller()` dont include it in the partial if you want better usage look into loaders such as requirejs

Comment: I include the script from partial.html, which is the point of my question.  I know this works if move the script tag to index.html

Comment: Again I would not recommend that approach you should use a script loader such as requirejs if you want to organize your dependencies or files

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think even with require.js, you could not achieve lazy loading without exposing $controllerProvider with Angular.  So while require.js would certainly help organize dependencies better, it will not solve this issue directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `[RequireJS][1]`
it provides a good and easy way for you to load your `.js` files on the run.

for the dynamic controller loading part: you should write a provider (a service) which exposes some methods to register your controllers wile the angular app is running (take a look at `$controllerProvider` in angular docs)

i suggest you take a look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx) as it mentions how to fully customize your application regarding the script loading and controller registeration and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using custom directive and in directive you can load script using jquery getscript or jQuery ajax call, directive will fire when you load the partial