# Want to call external controller for angular route

Tags: angularjs

I have angular routes working, but I am getting stuck on particular piece I am not sure is possible. I want to use an external controller file.

Example of working code:

```
 app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/AngularViews/Home/index.html'
            }).when('/Login', {
                templateUrl: 'AngularViews/Account/index.html',
                controller: 'registerUser'
            }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });

    app.controller('registerUser', function($scope) {
        $scope.hello = 'test';
    })
```

What I want to do is something more like so:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/AngularViews/Home/index.html'
        }).when('/Login', {
            templateUrl: 'AngularViews/Account/index.html',
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

HTML for Template Login:

```
<script src="../../AngularScripts/Account/account.js"></script>
REGISTRATION

<div ng-controller="registerUser">
    {{hello}}
</div>
```

Account.js file:

```
app.controller('registerUser', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
    $scope.registerUser = function () {
        var createData = {
            "UserName": $scope.email,
            "Password": $scope.password,
            "ConfirmPassword": $scope.confirmpass
        };
        console.log(createData);
        return createData;
    };
})
```

When doing it the second way it keeps telling me registerUser is undefined because it can't find registerUser

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Dynamic loading a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674945/angularjs-dynamic-loading-a-controller)

Comment: Take a look at [http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/)

Comment: Those other posts aren't exactly what I am looking for I believe. If they are what I am looking for they aren't clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `registerUser` controller must be defined in the same app as the one your routes are defined in. If it's in another module that module needs to be injected as a dependency in your main app, and the script for `registerUser` controller must be brought in at the same time as your app definition. See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8x4THCCYvIRtUxRCXZL?p=preview).

Comment: So I seen you bought in the script "registerUserController" to the main index. With that wouldn't I have to bring in all my controllers. I wanted to bring in only the ones I need when I am on those views.

Comment: In that case you need something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx), It's what Im using to lazy load my controllers in a huge angular project.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('registerUser', function($scope, data) {
```

When this is called, then almost nothing happens. `angular.module.controller` tells angular that you want to register a controller, but the real registration happens later, when the application gets bootstrapped. Consequently any call during a running application is fruitless.

Registration of controllers is done via `$controllerProvider.register(name, function)`. Unfortunately you cannot directly access the `$controllerProvider` when the application is already running. We need to cheat. Add the following to your configuration block:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {
  ...
  app.$controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
```

In your `Account.js` file you can instantiate the controller with

```
app.$controllerProvider.register('registerUser', function($scope, data) {
```