# dynamically name an angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to name an angular controller dynamically, like so:

```
app.controller(dynamic_name_constructed_here, ...);
```

Right now, when I run my program, I get an error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument dynamic_name_constructed_here is not a function, got undefined
```

Is constructing the name the way I am constructing it allowed? If not, an explanation as to why this doesn't work would be awesome! If so, how can I eliminate this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Dynamic loading a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674945/angularjs-dynamic-loading-a-controller)

Comment: I think you provided `dynamic_name_constructed_here` as string instead of variable name.. That is what the error message says