# AngularJS controller reference becomes undefined

Tags: angularjs

I've just started learning AngularJS and built a small yet simple application, which consists of multiple controllers as shown here:

[image]

I have a `SiteMaster.html` page, inside this page I use `ng-view` as shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>  <!-- Consists of Routing  -->
    <script src="Templates/Params/paramsController.js"></script>

    <title>Angular Routing Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <h1>sitemaster Template</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the last script tag is the controller for the params page, Ideally I don't want this script tag reference on the SiteMaster instead I would like to place it inside the params.HTML page that way it's only loaded when it's required, now I've moved this script tag from the `SiteMaster.Html` to the `params.Html` page as shown here:

```
<script src="paramsController.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="paramsCtrl">
  <h1>
      Passed a parameter via url
  </h1>
</div>
```

Yet when I run the project I get the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/areq?p0=paramsCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

So my question is, how do I get this `paramsController.js` reference to work within the `params.html` page? instead of having it on the `SiteMaster.html` page?

Please note, when the `paramsController.js` is placed inside the `SiteMaster.Html` page it works as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

***Update***
After adding ocLazyLoad I have done the following:

Added the script reference to sitemaster.html

Inside my app.js I have done the following:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', "oc.lazyLoad"]);
```

Inside my paramsController.js I have the following:

```
angular.module("mainApp").controller('paramsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $ocLazyLoad) {

console.log($routeParams);

var param1 = $routeParams.page_number;

alert(param1);

});
```

And now I've hit a road block I'm unsure where or how I go about loading this controller via ocLazyLoad ? I following this documentation : https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

Comment: i think path of paramsController is incorrect in params.Html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your path is wrong. Change

```
<script src="paramsController.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="Templates/Params/paramsController.js"></script>
```

Also, include the following in your `<head>` section:

```
<base href="/">
```

And the second thing, I'm not sure, even that will not work as Angular has already been initialized. So you need to use a library like [ocLazyLoaded](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) to dynamically load resources.

Also, consider reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17675432/2405040

**Update:**

In your `params.html`

```
<!-- Remove this line
<script src="paramsController.js"></script>
-->

<div ng-controller="paramsCtrl">
    <h1>
        Passed a parameter via url
    </h1>
</div>
```

And now modify your `$routeProvider` configuration:

(From the docs https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router)

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/foo', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/Params/params.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                 // you can lazy load files for an existing module
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('Templates/Params/paramsController.js');
            }]
        }
    })
```

Comment: I've tried this, however I still get the same error, When you say add the following to the head section is that on the sitemaster or params.html page?

Comment: Not yet no, was just trying the following options you had provided

Comment: Just added an update after installing / configuring the ocLazyLoad, any help would be appreciated.